# eval() takes no keyword argument

Tags: python, tkinter, eval

### Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(win, width = 50, height = 20, bg = 'black', fg = 'lightgreen', wrap = tk.WORD)
text.pack()

text.tag_configure('prompt', foreground = 'magenta')
text.tag_configure('output', foreground = 'yellow')

text.insert('end', '>>> ', 'prompt')

def on_return(*args):
  cmd = text.get('prompt.last', 'end')
  if cmd:
     try:
       output = str(eval(cmd, globals = {"__builtins__":None}))
     except Exception as e:
       output = str(e)
  text.insert('end', '\n' + output, 'output')
  text.insert('end', '\n>>> ' + output, 'prompt')
  return 'break'

text.bind('<Return>', on_return)

win.mainloop()
```

In order to get this output: *eval() takes no keyword argument*, just type anything on the text widget and press enter.

What should I do to avoid this output?

Comment: Don't pass the `globals` argument by keyword? It's positional only, just delete `globals = `.

Comment: The error message is quite clear. Don't use a keyword argument. See the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 First of all, If it were clear, I would have understood. Words such as *clear* are for lousy explainers.

Comment: It was indeed clear. If you didn't understand it, it means you were not only using keyword arguments without knowing what they are, but also not looking them up even when they were specified in an error message. That's not what this site is intended for.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I find the docs unclear to me.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 So questions like this aren't to be posted?

Comment: There are a ton of websites explaining pretty much every Python concept, not just the official documentation. Are you saying the only way for you to resolve an error message like the one above is to get the answer handed to you without ever understanding the problem?

Comment: "So questions like this aren't to be posted?" In theory, according to the site guidelines, that is correct. Users are ostensibly expected to be able to do at least some basic debugging for this kind of error.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Can you give me a link? So I don't do this again.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask] are good places to start.

Comment: Why are you using `eval` here anyway? It's quite dangerous, especially if you don't know what you doing (like you), and there seems to be no reason for it.

Comment: @Atlas435 Nobody else will be using this. I'm learning how to use it. Also, why is it important for there to be a reason?

Comment: @Nameless  Often folks give style and best practice advice here so that was likely the reason for the comment on eval.   your reason for using it (education) was perfectly fine.   Just folks would recommend not putting eval anywhere near a production application...

Comment: @LhasaDad Yes, thank you for the reminder. I've read about that issue, but eval has other arguments which let you avoid this issues. That's why I'm learning them just In case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you need to remove the 'globals =' from the parameter passing in the dictionary.   The correct line is:

```
output = str(eval(cmd, {"__builtins__":None}))
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you a declare a function, the arguments can be passed by name or by keyword. However, it is possible to declare a function so that positional or keyword passing is disallowed. This is used by many built-in functions such as `eval` and `range` to reduce the call-time, to allow the library owner to freely rename parameters, and to forbid weird invocation order. [See PEP 570 for more.](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/#performance)

To call these functions, you must give the arguments in the correct order. If you want to only give `eval` local variables, not global, just pass the default value for `global`: `eval(expression, None, your_locals)`.

You can declare such a function by putting a forward slash `/` and an asterisk `*` in the argument list. Arguments before the slash are positional only, arguments between the slash and the asterisk are keyword-or-positional, and arguments after the asterisk are keyword only.

For example, to get behavior similar to eval, you would declare:

```py
def eval2(expression, globals=None, locals=None, /):
    pass
```

`eval2` accepts only positional arguments. If you were to invoke it with a keyword, you would get an exception:

```py
eval2('print("hello", location)', locals={'location':'world'})
...
TypeError: eval2() got some positional-only arguments passed as keyword arguments: 'locals'
```

You can also declare a function that takes a mix of positional-only, normal, and keyword-only arguments:

```py
def example_function(positional1, positional2, /, keyword_or_positional1, keyword_or_positional2, *, keyword1, keyword2):
    pass
```

Incidentally, this is also why you see slashes in some signatures in Python's help utility:

```py
help(hasattr)
...
hasattr(obj, name, /)
```

Because obj and name are before a slash, they cannot be passed as keyword arguments. For some reason, the slash is not included in the HTML documentation unless there are normal arguments as well as positional-only.